# Python: Insert image into signature field of a PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pdfrw

I have a PDF 'template' file and a PNG image. 
I've been able to insert text into the PDF using the `pdfrw` library where I created a dictionary of the fields in the PDF with values for it, but I was wondering if there's a way I can insert an image in the same way, corresponding to a particular field.